# ClassDefNotFoundError with local aar

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror, aar

I know it seems that this question was already asked, but they are slightly different, and I could not find a solution for my problem.

I have an Android app which depends on several aar libs which in turn are dependent on (pure java) jars. While developing in Android Studio, I include all aars and jars as a dependency from my companies local nexus. This works as intended.

however, for deployment we have local aar files which already include their jar dependencies inside their `libs` folder. Inside the deployed build.gradle we have the following entries defined to include them:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs '../../libs'
    }

     maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile ":NameOfAarFile:1.0.0@aar"
    compile ":NameOfAnotherAar:1.0.0@aar"

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

If I open the project in android studio, gradle does its checks and lets me build it. It opens, but as soon as you're trying to use functionality originated in a jar which was in an aar I get the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

So I de-compiled the apk from outputs, run them through `dex2jar` and looked at the classes with `jd-gui` just to find out, that they are at their expected place.

Now I'm really wondering were the `NoClassDefFoundError` is coming from, or -
even more important - how to get rid of it?

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#Considerations) mentions:

> A library module can include a JAR library
>
> You can develop a library module that itself includes a JAR library;
>   however you need to manually edit the dependent app modules's build
>   path and add a path to the JAR file.

I really want to leave the jars included inside the aar, if possible.

If necessary, I will provide more info.

Comment: What's the total count of the methods? If it's above 65K, you must enable multidex.

Comment: how to count them? Do just Java Methods count towards this limit? But I suspect 65k is way more  than I got (estimate I don't have even 10k methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what happened. 
It works if you disable `InstantRun` in Android Studio.